# Long-term Storage of Vishniak in Corny Keg (Stainless Steel)

Tags: vodka, keg

I am looking to make a bunch of Cherry Vishniak this year and I am trying to figure out how best to store it for a long period of time (1-5+ years). I have [several corny kegs](https://www.homebrewing.org/AIH-New-175-Gallon-Ball-Lock-Keg_p_7547.html) that I am thinking about storing it in but I don't know if vodka would work well stored in a stainless steel container for long periods of time.

The recipe for the Cherry Vishniak is

```
3 cups of water
3 cups of white sugar
3 cups of vodka
~2lbs of bing cherries
```

Boil 3 cups of water and 3 cups of sugar to make a simple syrup. Once cool add that to a container with the rest of the ingredients and let sit for a very long period of time.

I have found reference online to aluminum and stainless containers altering the taste of the contents (mainly aluminum) but nothing really related to how long a 304 stainless steel keg can hold something like a cherry vishniak and if it will alter the taste after a few years.

Does anyone know if the stainless steel corning keg would work for making some vishniak?

Comment: You might get an answer in the homebrew SE site.

Answer (score 1):

I would say try it with a small batch!

My only concern would be, if there was a pressure build up (temperature changes) in the keg, you might end up with fizzy vodka/Cherry Vishniak, now that may be interesting (I just googled it as I was typing and it is actually a thing)

You learn something every day, I may try it tomorrow (force carb) in a spare keg.

[image]